# How can I find a member with a specific nickname?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am wondering how I can find a user with a specific nickname in a specific server?

Comment: Nevermind, I just learned how XD

```mem.displayName```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.guilds.cache.get("Guild ID").members.cache.find(member => member.displayName === "Nickname")`